# Pattern matching on C++ vector

Tags: c++, templates, generics, pattern-matching

I have several functions approximately of the form

```
struct ins;
enum class op_t {
    // ...
};

std::vector<ins> optimise_addone(std::vector<ins> prog)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < prog.size() - 1; i++) {
        auto &a = prog[i];
        auto &b = prog[i + 1];
        if (a.code == op_t::SET && a.op.which() == 1 && boost::get<uint16_t>(a.op) == 1 && b.code == op_t::ADD) {
            a = make_ins(op_t::INC);
            prog.erase(prog.begin() + i + 1);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    return prog;
}

std::vector<ins> optimise_storeload(std::vector<ins> prog)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < prog.size() - 3; i++) {
        auto &a = prog[i];
        auto &b = prog[i + 1];
        auto &c = prog[i + 2];
        auto &d = prog[i + 3];
        if (a.code == op_t::SET && c.code == op_t::SET && b.code == op_t::STORE && d.code == op_t::LOAD && a.op == c.op) {
            a = make_ins(op_t::DUP);
            b = make_ins(op_t::SET, c.op);
            c = make_ins(op_t::STORE);
            prog.erase(prog.begin() + i + 3);
            i += 3;
        }
    }
    return prog;
}
```

They each take in a vector, find a patching subsection of it (of size N), and modify it in some arbitrary way

It seems to me that there should be a way of generalising this, using templates or function objects or similar, but I can't see it myself.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

*Higher-order functions* solve your issue nicely. Below is a C++14 solution.

Here's how the final interface will look:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
patchVector<2>(v, [](auto& a, auto& b){
    std::cout << a + b << " ";
});
```

Prints:

> 3 5 7 9

---

```
template <typename Vector, typename F, std::size_t... Is>
auto callWithSlice(std::size_t i, Vector& v, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return f(v[i + Is]...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Vector, typename F>
auto patchVector(Vector v, F&& f)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - N + 1; ++i)
    {
        callWithSlice(i, v, std::forward<F>(f), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    }
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lbuKGiG8ZbgjqO0T)

Comment: This looks excellent! Thanks very much, however, it doesn't appear to allow me to remove elements from the vector? (`prog.erase(...)` in my original) Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: You could pass the iterator to the first item in the subset in the call to `f`. Example: `f(v.begin() + i, v[i + Is]...);`. You can then use it in the lambda as the first argument.

Comment: Actually no, that doesn't work either? Since i need to do `vec.erase(it)` and i haven't got a reference to the vector..

Comment: @LordAro: there are many ways you can solve that. You could pass `vec` to `f` as an extra parameter, you could pass a *function object* that given an iterator calls `vec.erase`, or you could capture `vec` in the lambda by reference...

Comment: Guess that would work. At the risk of being subjective, which do you think would be best?

Comment: Especially since the a, b,... parameters are just by reference, rather than iterators